# change background color using react color picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, color-picker, react-color

I have a section in which I want users to be able to change the background color using react color picker and react-redux, unfortunately, the background color is not changing / not updating to a new color.

Live code in codesandbox: [change background color](https://codesandbox.io/s/change-color-kkm6l?file=/src/Components/Settings.js:0-1162)

Source code:

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { ChromePicker } from "react-color";
import Details from "./Details";

const Settings = () => {
  const fields = useSelector((state) => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [colorRgb, setColorRgb] = useState("#000");

  useEffect(() => {
    updateColor();
  }, []);

  const updateColor = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "change",
      name: "socialColor",
      value: colorRgb
    });
  };
  console.log("current color", colorRgb);
  console.log("current color", fields.color);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Details />
        <h1>Edit </h1>
        <div className="container">
          <ChromePicker
            renderers={false}
            color={colorRgb}
            onChange={(e) => setColorRgb(e.hex)}
          />
          <span
            className="testa"
            style={{
              background: fields.color,
              color: "#fff"
            }}
          >
            Change my background color
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

What is wrong with my code.?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set background in syntax of `rgba(r, g, b, a)` instead of `{r, g, b, a}` which is invalid css

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { ChromePicker } from "react-color";

const Settings = () => {
  const fields = useSelector((state) => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [colorRgb, setColorRgb] = useState(fields.color);

  useEffect(() => {
    updateColor();
  }, []);

  const updateColor = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "change",
      name: "socialColor",
      value: colorRgb
    });
  };
  console.log("current color", colorRgb);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Edit </h1>
        <div className="container">
          <ChromePicker
            renderers={false}
            color={colorRgb}
            onChange={(e) => setColorRgb(e.rgb)}
          />
          <span
            className="testa"
            style={{
              background:
                "rgba(" +
                colorRgb.r +
                "," +
                colorRgb.g +
                "," +
                colorRgb.b +
                "," +
                colorRgb.a +
                ")",
              color: "#fff"
            }}
          >
            Change my background color
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only calling the `updateColor` function which calls `dispatch` one time when the component mounts.  This doesn't make any sense because your redux value will always be black.

If you want to store "pending" changes in the component then you would use a local component state and call `dispatch` when clicking a "Submit" button.

Probably you want to call `dispatch` on every change and get rid of the local `useState`.

@ibra is correct about needing to format the color object into a string but you can write it more concisely.

It's up to you whether you want to convert from an object to a string before you store it in redux or after you retrieve it.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { ChromePicker } from "react-color";
import Details from "./Details";

export const rgbaString = ({r, g, b, a = 1}) => `rgba(${r},${g},${b},${a})`

const Settings = () => {
  const colorRgb = useSelector((state) => state.color);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onChangeColor = (e) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "change",
      name: "color",
      value: e.rgb
    });
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Details />
        <h1>Edit </h1>
        <div className="container">
          <ChromePicker
            renderers={false}
            color={colorRgb}
            onChange={onChangeColor}
          />
          <span
            className="testa"
            style={{
              background: rgbaString(colorRgb),
              color: "#fff"
            }}
          >
            Change my background color
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem will be fixed if you get the hex code instead of rgb

**your code**

```
   <ChromePicker
     renderers={false}
     color={colorRgb}
     onChange={(e) => colorChange(e.rgb)}
   />
```

**must be**

```
   <ChromePicker
     renderers={false}
     color={colorRgb}
     onChange={(e) => colorChange(e.hex)}
   />
```

Comment: ok then how can I add the opacity on a selected color? because react color with hex does not allow alpha?

Comment: You can use it like this `style={{ background: \`rgba(${colorRgb.r},${colorRgb.g},${colorRgb.b},${colorRgb.a})\`, color: "#fff" }}`

Comment: I have updated the code pen its not working check out let me know if it works https://codesandbox.io/s/change-color-kkm6l?file=/src/Components/Settings.js